# Display result from an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join

I would like to display results from an INNER JOIN the easiest way as possible. I tried this but that does not work:

```
<?php
        $serveur  = "localhost";
        $login = "root";
        $pass = "root"; 

        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serveur;dbname=test2", $login, $pass);

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //On place notre requête dans une variable
            $jointure_int =
                "SELECT Inscrits.prenom, Commentaires.commentaire
                FROM Inscrits
                INNER JOIN Commentaires
                ON Inscrits.id = Commentaires.id_inscrit";

            //On prépare notre requête
            $requete = $conn->prepare($jointure_int);

            //On exécute notre requête
            $resultat = $requete->execute();

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($resultat);
            echo "</pre>";

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) { 
            echo 'Echec : ' . $e->getMessage(); 
        }
?>
```

I know my SQL statement works fine (I've tested it in MySQL). I'm using PDO. The only thing that is print_ here is the number "1".

***I would like to understand why this code does not work. Isn't my variable $resultat an array? Can't I print_r the result from a join? What is the easiest war to display this result (am I obliged to fetch everything?)?***

I created this ode only for self-training purpose, I do not mean to apply it in any website by the way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute()` just returns boolean value which indicates there was an error. so, `print_r($resultat)` prints `true` or `false`.

The answer for your question:

> What is the easiest war to display this result

use `fetchAll()`. You can see it here [PHP manaual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then if I followed it well, my variable $resultat above can only store TRUE(1) or FALSE(0)? I have to fetch the result before to get an array and to be able to print_r this after, it that right?

Comment: @PierreGiraud Right. 1 for `true`, 0 for `false` which means failure on executing query. You can fetch rows after `execute()` returns `true`.

There are two functions related to fetching rows from resultset. `fetchAll()` fetches all rows at once. `fetch()` fetches row by row every calls. `fetchAll()` would be better if there a few rows or you want print all rows at once but consumes much memories.